# ScalaFx: Bidirectional Binding with converter

Tags: scalafx

JavaFx has

```
Bindings.bindBidirectional(p1,p2,converter)
```

for binding properties with a converter.

What is the approach in ScalaFx ? I only know that you can bind properties
via

```
 prop2 <==> prop1
```

but how to include a converter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special way in ScalaFX use binding with the converter. You can simply use the JavaFX method and pass in ScalaFX properties and a converter.